# Full height/width background image

Tags: html, css

i have a background image and i want to use it on my website but the problemn is i cant make it full height and width in any size, help me and please, check the codes below

current code, code #1 : haft and not full

```
body {
    background: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CHRISTINE-BACKGOURND.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    /* background-size: cover; */
    height: auto!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

code # 2

```
body {
    background: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CHRISTINE-BACKGOURND.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

i cant make it full width and height :( please help

Comment: height:100% should be given

Comment: I have a feeling that photo is kinda NSFW.

Answer (score 3):

```css
html{
  width:100%,height:100%;
  }
body{ 
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0G3w.jpg);
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

HTML

```
<body></body>
```

CSS

```
html{
  width:100%,height:100%;
  }
body{ 
  background: url(../image.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
```